# Help me find a good system mechanic

Tags: game-recommendation, homebrew

I'm looking for a system mechanic that I could use in my homebrew campaign. I don't mind borrowing a mechanic from a well known system, like WFRP, DnD or WoD, but the truth is I am not that familiar with different systems to know where to look and I didn't like any of those that I found.

I know what I'm looking for though (most important features first)

1. **Classless system**
   And preferably character development without levels, that seems to be accompanying this process
2. **Degrees of success**
   So the player after rolling can get not only botch-fail-succeed result, but, like in Storyteller, he can "fix a car just enough to roll to the garage", "fix it so it holds for a few months" or "fix it forever"
3. **Light on the amount of rolling**
   I'd rather throw a one complicated roll than a couple simple ones.
4. **Difference between high-risk-high-reward and persistent nudging tactics**
   For example, I would like a character with a massive unwieldy axe feel different from one with a handy and accurate cutlass. Also, a skilled character with a regular pistol should feel different from an unskilled one with a fancy pistol. Also, difference between a genius relying on a strike of brilliance and a hardworking, bit-by-bit craftsman. Repeat *ad nauseum*.
5. **Fair amount of degrees of freedom**
   In DnD GM has only one degree of freedom - difficulty. In Storyteller - 3, dice pool, difficulty and target no of successes. I prefer the latter.
6. **Passive defenses**
   The player do not has to sacrifice his attack to dodge, defenses should be at least reflexive, like WFRP dodge.

DnD, either edition fails on 1,2 and 5.
WFRP: fails 1,2,5
Storyteller (cWoD): fails 3 and 6 and after Revised it actually lost 4 as well (shooting a derringer should be easier than shooting a hand cannon, right, White Wolf?)
Storytelling (nWoD): now fails 2,4,5. It just replaced old issues with new ones.
The rest is not familiar to me enough to really judge, and most open source lightweight systems just simply lack the depth or no 2.

Comment: I don't have a good idea what exactly you're looking for here. Do you want an entire system to layer your homebrew setting on top of, or are you looking for the core mechanical ideas to mash-up into your own collection of powers, artifacts, et al.?

Comment: As much as I would like rpg.SE to give me an entire mechanic system, I will accept answers that describe a basic premise of the system (like for WFRP - you roll d%, success is when it falls under your skill, difficulty is handled by adding/subtracting a set amount from the roll result before checking) with a brief explanation which of those requirements are met and why. I think I might respond to that question myself to set an example, but that answer wouldn't satisfy me obviously. I am using Storyteller now, but because of its shortcomings I'd like to exchange it for something else.

Comment: You're basically asking us to design a system for you. I'm voting to close as "too broad". If you meant to ask a more focused design question, or you meant to ask for a recommendation of a game you could/should play/steal from, you can edit the question to say so.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that and edit the question in a bit. I would like the rpg.SE to give me examples of games, that have a mechanic that fills all (or nearly all) of the above requirements, so that I can look them up and modify. The question is asked because with a vast library of existing games I would have to go through a considerable amount of systems that are total misses.

Comment: List questions are not on topic; we don't accept questions that simply want to generate ideas. This is not a discussion forum. Please read [About]. A question should be such that it (at least conceivably) has *one, true, correct answer.* There needs to be clear ways to say *this answer* is better than *that answer.*

Comment: I'm not sure why this sys-rec question has been put on hold. The asker has listed his desires and rationales and explained why the systems he has considered are lacking. Why is this Q different from all the others? Is it because he originally thought he wanted just a mechanic instead of a system?

Comment: @gomad Yes, at first. It was broad and unfocused. Now it's still closed because the asker has clarified that they want us to [curate a list for them to browse](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/whats-so-problematic-about-a-recommendation-question-having-potentially-hundred).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Could you please advise me on how to make this question conform to the rules? I would really like SE to help and sure enough I could make a fake "game recommendation" question with exactly these requirements, but I would like to be fair to the community.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, so I'm not sure how to focus this. If you hop into chat a few times in the day, you should be able to find some of our users who are good at workshopping questions into a tight form that suits the site. Alternatively, SE just might not be the tool for this job, and you might consider a forum—asking for piles of suggestions is ok on its own, it just clashes with the SE voting system.

Comment: Well, I actually thought that there might just be a system like I described. The kind of answer gomad provided is precisely the one I would like to see. I also thought that "one, true answer" can be selected by rating the maximum conformance to the requirements. I also believed that it is not too broad, as the requirements are pretty specific, so there must be at most a single-sigit number (I would personally esteimate less than five) of systems that fit them, with one being the best fit. That's why I thought it might be okay to ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Fate Core](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core-menu)

I recommend Fate Core for your use. Let's take it point-by-point:

> Classless system

Fate has neither classes nor levels. You build the character you want instead of ordering one from the menu.

> Degrees of success

Fate has by default 4 outcomes: Failure, Tie, Success, Success with Style. Additionally, every successful roll has *Shifts* - degrees by which the opposition was beaten. Shifts power all sorts of stunts and determine Success vs. Success with Style. You can place more emphasis on shifts if you like, too.

> Light on the amount of rolling

All rolls are about the same level of complexity in Fate...they're all 4dF (dF are Fate / Fudge dice - d6s with 2 "+" sides, 2 "-" sides and 2 blank sides). Aspects can be invoked to earn re-rolls, but that is in my considerable experience (I've been playing Fate since 2006) rare compared to just using them for a +2.

> Difference between high-risk-high-reward and persistent nudging tactics

Fate does a great job of dealing with the cinematic "the whole team contributes to the massive stroke that takes the bad guy down" situation, which clearly differentiates between individual contributions and team efforts and puts **everyone's success** on the line for a single roll, too. Very much delineated between low-risk, individual contributions and high-risk team efforts.

By default, gear doesn't matter that much in Fate. But there are settings where particular gear matters a lot - fighter planes, giant mechs, etc.. But Fate is not where you go for a difference between two revolvers...unless you *make* the game about that.

> Fair amount of degrees of freedom

The Fate GM has plenty to work with - opposing skills, flat difficulties, scene, situation, and character aspects. The whole [Fate Fractal](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/extras#the-bronze-rule-aka-the-fate-fractal) is there for you to manipulate.

> Passive defenses

In Fate, every attack is met with a defense roll. However, players can choose to just take a hit (for instance one that was intended for someone else) and can also opt for [Full Defense](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/conflicts#full-defense), exchanging an action for a better defense.

Fate is a great, modern, well supported game. It's available for pay-what-you want, so absolutely worth your time if what I have said here is attractive.